# How can I bind data to an event in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, callback

Here is a boiled down version of the sort of code I've written:

```
var cb_gen, item, list, label, token;

cb_gen = function (token_string) {
    return function (data) {
        var msg = "logout of [" + token_string + "] ";
        msg += (typeof(data.error) == "undefined") ? "succeeded" : "failed";
        console.log(msg);
    };
};

for (item in list) {
    label = "API_" + item;
    token = make_token(item);
    app_resources.event.once(label, cb_gen(token));
}
```

This has the side effect of generating a callback function for each iteration of the loop. What I'd rather do is something like the following:

```
var cb_gen, item, list, label, token;

callback = function (data, token_string) {
    var msg = "logout of [" + token_string + "] ";
    msg += (typeof(data.error) == "undefined") ? "succeeded" : "failed";
    console.log(msg);
};

for (item in list) {
    label = "API_" + item;
    token = make_token(item);
    app_resources.event.once(label, callback);
    app_resources.event.add_bound_data(label, token);
}
```

Of course I am not aware of any such method as "add_bound_data". The first code that I listed above will work and so I'm not in dire need of a solution like the second one. However, if my loop gets large, something like the second example will be very nice. I'd appreciate any insight those in the know are able to share.

- thanks

Comment: You say that your code is 'boiled down', but it's also not valid javascript. It will be easier to understand what you're asking if you give us valid code.

Comment: What is this? CoffeeScript?

Comment: Sorry 'bout that. I fixed the syntax errors above. I ran both of these through jshint and it did not complain.